Why do I have a version mismatch when installing CUDA in wsl?
I am trying to install Tensorflow 2 on wsl 2 on a Win 10 PC. I have followed the instructions here and tried to install CUDA version 11.8. as can be seen in the code I run
Installer code for CUDA 11.8
It seems everything has gone well but when I run the command nvidia-smi, the CUDA version is shown to be 12.4.
screen shot of nvidia-smi
Why is this happening?
I tried to uninstall and did a fresh install, but the result is still the same.
